# mysqli fetch_array does not iterate

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please note the following code:  **CLASS**

```
namespace hfdDB;
class HFD_DB
{
/**
 * @return \mysqli
 */
public static function getConnection()
{
    require_once('globals.php');

    return new \mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);

}

/**
 *
 */
public static function getAllItems()

{
    $conn = self::getConnection();  //open connection
    $sql="SELECT * FROM HFD_ITEMS"; //command text
    $cmdAllItems = $conn->prepare($sql); // command
    $cmdAllItems->execute(); //execute command
    $allItems = $cmdAllItems->get_result(); //assign result
    echo $allItems->num_rows." rows returned<br>";
    $itemsArray = []; //array for storing result rows

    echo "result set (first row): ";
    var_dump($allItems);
    echo "<br>";

    if (!empty($allItems) ) {
        while ($item = $allItems->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) ;
        {
            echo "fetch result: ";
            var_dump($item);
            echo "<br>";
            array_push($itemsArray, $item);  //add to array
        }

        return json_encode($itemsArray); //return json
    } else {
        return "NO DATA"; //return error
    }
}
```

================================== login.php ====

```
<?php
/**
* Created by PhpStorm.
* User: Mark
* Date: 1/10/2016
* Time: 7:08 PM
*/



require_once("HFD_DB.php");
$allItems_json = \hfdDB\HFD_DB::getAllItems();
if (!empty($allItems_json)) {
    echo "Data: ";
echo $allItems_json;
} else {
    echo "NO DATA";

}
```

and my results: (when run from phpStorm IDE)

```
6730 rows returned
result set (first row): 
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) 
{
    ["current_field"]=> int(0)
    ["field_count"]=> int(10) 
    ["lengths"]=> NULL 
    ["num_rows"]=> int(6730) 
    ["type"]=> int(0) 
} 


fetch result: NULL

Data: [null]
```

---

Note: that 6370 is the expected number of rows for this query. So why don't I iterate 6370 times through the loop?

I am no stranger to Coding or to SQL, though I am new to PHP.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: try removing `var_dump($allItems);`. i suspect it's causing problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out my problem was simple: `json_encode` takes a second argument: depth.  Depth it turns out, equates to the maximum number of rows returned. The default is 512.

Changing the code to:

```
json_encode($itemsArray,10000)
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You fetched an array of arrays. You should use a for - each loop.

```
while ($item = $allItems->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) ;
    {
        echo "fetch result: ";
        var_dump($item);
        echo "<br>";
        array_push($itemsArray, $item);  //add to array
    }
```

Runs once, assigning the entire array of arrays structure. ->fetch_array fetches everything in one go, not like fetch_assoc.

```
ForEach (($allItems->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) as $Item)
    {
        echo "fetch result: ";
        var_dump($item);
        echo "<br>";
        array_push($itemsArray, $item);  //add to array
    }
```

Using the foreach you are iterating over the array of arrays and placing a Named (Assoc) array into the $item variable, which is what you were expecting.